# Converting xy coordinates to ternary space for ternary plot in R

Tags: r, plotly, ternary, ggtern

I have troubles creating a ternary plot. I tried both the functions in the `ggtern` and `Plotly` package. I have a set of (x,y) coordinates, all between `0`d and `1`. When I just do a regular `geom_point()` plot, I can nicely see the results in Cartesian space.

Then I have tried the `ggtern()` function after converting my (x,y) coordinates to ternary space but I get a very different result and the points don't show up with a similar distribution as in Cartesian space.
Since I want to make a ternary contour plot, it seems quite necessary I get a similar distribution of points as in Cartesian space.

I tried the following conversion, with different values for 'direction' option:

```
Ternary_Coords<-as.data.frame(t(XYToTernary(VarX,VarY),direction=2)))
```

But my points never look the same as on the cartesian plot.
What could the problem be?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to give us at least a subset of your data. Use `dput()`. Usually you construct a ternary plot from a, b, c data (3 variables that sum to 1). Those 3 dimensional coordinates are converted to two dimensional data, x, y in order to plot them in a 2-dimensional plane. You are using a function that would convert the 2-dimensional data back to 3-dimensional data which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Apologies I did not provide a dataset, I am quite new to the forum...Well, actually the  TernaryPlot command and ggtern command require 3D Barycentric coordinates while I had 2D cartesian coordinates. But I found a way to solve this, using cart2bary, delivering the 3D format that these functions require. Thank you for your suggestion.